# What is the way to make kubernetes nodes have `providerID` spec after creation (manually)?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

I'm expecting that `kubectl get nodes <node> -o yaml` to show the `spec.providerID` (see reference below) once the kubelet has been provided the additional flag `--provider-id=provider://nodeID`.  I've used `/etc/default/kubelet` file to add more flags to the command line when kubelet is start/restarted.  (On a k8s 1.16 cluster)  I see the additional flags via a `systemctl status kubelet --no-pager` call, so the file is respected.

However, I've not seen the value get returned by `kubectl get node <node> -o yaml` call.  I was thinking it had to be that the node was already registered, but I think kubectl re-registers when it starts up.  I've seen the log line via `journalctl -u kubelet` suggest that it has gone through registration.

How can I add a provider ID to a node manually?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#nodespec-v1-core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How a `kubelet` is configured on the node itself is separate (AFAIK) from its definition in the `master` control plane, which is responsible for updating state in the central `etcd` store; so it's possible for these to fall out of sync. i.e., you need to communicate to the control place to update its records.

In addition to Subramanian's suggestion, `kubectl patch node` would also work, and has the added benefit of being easily reproducible/scriptable compared to manually editing the YAML manifest; it also leaves a "paper trail" in your shell history should you need to refer back. Take your pick :) For example,

```sh
$ kubectl patch node my-node -p '{"spec":{"providerID":"foo"}}'
node/my-node patched
$ kubectl describe node my-node | grep ProviderID
ProviderID:                   foo
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: how to reset the providerID if it is wrongly set ? I encountered forbidden errors.

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot patch the value, if it was already set.


`kubectl patch node ocp-master01 -p '{"spec":{"providerID":"foo"}}'
The Node "ocp-master01" is invalid: spec.providerID: Forbidden: node updates may not change providerID except from "" to valid`

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the node config and append providerID information under spec section.

```
kubectl edit node <Node Name> 

...

spec:
   podCIDR:
   providerID:
```